# How to sign request with pem file from another domain?

Tags: php, ssl, request

I need make request with pem key, but pem files is located on another domain

if i set pem file with key on my host, request with guzzle works fine. But if i tried to read pem file from another host, it doesn't work.

This request is working

```
            [
                'cert' => '/var/www/api/container/src/cert.pem'
            ]
        );
```

This request is not working, but i need it

```
            [
                   'cert' => file_get_contents('https://certs/cert.pem',)
            ]
        );
```

The error shows me, that guzzle httpclient can't find ssl for request.

Comment: You have a public access pem file :O?

Comment: You can't sign anything with someone else's certificate.  You have to have access to the private key to create a digital signature.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature